# Xamarin Android C# Start Service 'else' not called

Tags: c#, android, if-statement, xamarin, service

I have buttons that give the ability to start or stop the app's background service, but for some reason my 'else' call in the button's click event isnt being activated if the service is already running.

Heres the whole button code, hope someone knows why it doesnt call:

```
private void StartServiceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Application.Context.GetSystemService("com.prg.NotificationService") == null)
        {
            Application.Context.StartService(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Service already running", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
```

im caching intent in OnCreate, here is the setup:

`intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(NotificationService));`

Comment: What service is your `intent` variable pointing to?

Comment: Ah forgot to mention that - im caching this OnCreate, here is the intent setup: `intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(NotificationService));`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code as opposed to adding it into the comments. It is very difficult to read code in the comments, and this way people don't have to read through the comments to get the additional information about the question.

Comment: My guess would be that the name of the service you are checking for is not the same as the name of the service you are starting. I would debug this by getting a list of all running services and seeing what is in the list, then starting your service and checking the list again. The answer to the `some reason` is that your `if` clause must be returning true each time.

Comment: `Toast.MakeText(this, "Service already running)", ToastLength.Long).Show();` please check your syntax, especially " is behind )

Comment: The ")" behind is just part of the string , i just missed to edit that out

Answer (score 1):

[Here is about the `GetSystemService` method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Context.GetSystemService/p/System.String/), this method is to get system service not to get your custom service. You need use `ActivityManager` to get all service which is running on your device and find which one is what you want to start or stop.

Please use the under code to achieve your goal:

```
private void StartServiceButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MyService myService = new MyService();
    if (!isServiceRun("MyService"))
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Service not running", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        Application.Context.StartService(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Service already running", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        StopService(new Intent(this,typeof(MyService)));
    }
}
public  bool isServiceRun( string className)
{
    bool isRun = false;
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
    IList<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> serviceList = activityManager.GetRunningServices(40);
    int size = serviceList.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Error("Service Name=====", serviceList[i].Service.ClassName);
        if (serviceList[i].Service.ClassName.Contains(className) == true)
        {
            isRun = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isRun;
}
```

### Note:

[Here is the usage about `Service` in Xamarin.Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/), please don't forget add `[Service]` attribute.